# Can I use Google Sheets to help me with Mendelian Inheritance Tables?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in Google Sheets that looks similar to the following:

| Parent | Trait 1 A | Trait 1 B | Trait 2 A | Trait 2 B | Trait 3 A | Trait 3 B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

It is meant to calculate Mendelian inheritance with "0" representing a recessive allele and "1" representing a dominate allele. For this application, there is no difference between an offspring having a "01" inheritance or a "10" inheritance; both are just labeled as heterozygous.

I want to create a calculated table with all the possible genetic combos of the offspring. For this example, the result should return a table that looks like this:

| Offspring | Trait 1 | Trait 2 | Trait 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 00 | 00 | 01 |
| B | 00 | 00 | 11 |
| C | 00 | 01 | 01 |
| D | 00 | 01 | 11 |
| E | 00 | 11 | 01 |
| F | 00 | 11 | 11 |

Is there a way to have Google Sheets automatically calculate all of the possibilities, or am I doomed to write all of these out by hand? Note: It doesn't have to calculate probabilities at this stage; it just needs to show the possible unique offspring "genetics."

Comment: There are only 3 Traits in the application, a Red value, a Green value, and a Blue value. I will add this information to the question.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. All the relevant details should be included directly in the question body. Comments are intended to ask for clarification or suggestions to improve the post. Please [edit] the question to include all the relevant details directly into it. Also show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Formula

```
=LET(rng,B2:G3,
  s,LAMBDA(r,c,n,cc,nn, MAP(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
    TOCOL(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(r),2),
    SEQUENCE(1,c,n,0),SEQUENCE(1,cc,nn,0))))),48,1), 
    LAMBDA(x, TEXT(INDEX(TOCOL(rng),x),"0")))),
  a,s(2,32,1,16,2), b,{s(1,16,7,0,0);s(2,16,8,16,7)},
  c,s(6,8,3,8,4), d,s(12,4,9,4,10), e,s(24,2,5,2,6),
  f,s(48,1,11,1,12),
  SORTN(({a&b,c&d,e&f}),48,2,(a+b&" "&c+d&" "&e+f),1))
```

1. If you numbered the cells in the first row 1-6 and the second row  7-12, all the pair combinations could be represented in a 48x6 array.

   - this ignores the fact that there are only 2 possible values for all numbers
   - this also ignores the fact that `10` and `01` are considered equivalent in your problem.
   - there really only seem to be 27 possible combinations but it was simpler to assume 48 since the results would need to be filtered for duplicates at some point regardless, and the formula would be more extensible should the criteria change.
2. Using those two arrays, you can map the right value from the parents' array into each position in the 48x6 combinations array.

- The LAMBDA function stored in `s` is designed to generate a sequence of 48 numbers, and then replace each of those 48 numbers with whatever value is in the parents' array at the position that matches the number being replaced.

  - for example `a` is  `s(2,32,1,16,2)` and the LAMBDA function creates a sequence of 32 number 1s followed by 16 number 2s (48 numbers).  Then each 1 is replaced by the value from the parents array at INDEX 1, and all the 2s are replaced by the value in the parents array at INDEX 2.
  - each letter a-f represents a column from 1-6 in the 48x6 array.

3. SORTN is used to eliminate duplicates.

   - since `01` and `10` are equivalent and the only values used are `0` or `1`, adding A and B of each trait allows comparing for uniqueness `0+1=1+0` `0+0=0+0` `1+1=1+1`
   - This addition is done to each column pair and then they are joined as strings `(a+b&" "&c+d&" "&e+f)`

- SORTN's `display_ties_mode` argument is set to `2` which means return only the first of matching values.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

[image]

To separate A and B of each trait into separate columns simply replace `{a&b,c&d,e&f}` with `{a,b,c,d,e,f}` in the SORTN function.

[image]